# Flutter, can't get numbers from contact(ios emulator)

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to get numbers from contact, on android everything works, but on ios nothing works, not even asking for permission, and in the console there are no errors. i don't know why it doesn't work.
P.S I have set permissions on both ios and android.

Here is my code :

```
void _filterContacts(String query) {
    List<Contact> filteredList = [];
    if (query.isNotEmpty) {
      for (Contact contact in _allContacts) {
        if (contact.displayName.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
          filteredList.add(contact);
        }
      }
    } else {
      filteredList = List.of(_allContacts);
    }
    setState(() {
      _filteredContacts = filteredList;
    });
  }

 void _loadContacts() async {
    bool isGranted = await Permission.contacts.status.isGranted;
    if (!isGranted) {
      isGranted = await Permission.contacts.request().isGranted;
      print('Запрос разрешения на доступ к контактам');
    }
    if (isGranted) {
      List<Contact> allContacts = await FastContacts.getAllContacts();
      setState(() {
        _allContacts = allContacts;
        _filteredContacts = List.of(_allContacts);
      });
    }
  }
```

I haven't tried anything because I have no idea where to dig.
An acquaintance says that it may not work on an emulator, but it may work on a real device. Is this true ?